# Query de INSERT não funciona dentro de um loop

Tags: php, query, pdo, loop, foreach

Então galera, eu não estou conseguindo resolver esse problema de uma query dentro de um foreach loop não executar. Primeiramente eu pensei que era algo errado com pdo->beginTransaction então eu comentei essa parte e deixei somente código puro.

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["nome"])):
        try{
            // Começo da validação
            //$pdo->beginTransaction();
            // Validação do campo nome
            if ($_POST["nome"] != null):
                $procurarnome=$pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=$name");
                $procurarnome->execute();
            else:
                die("Houve um erro no sistema, contate um administrador!");
            endif;
            // Validação dos campos dinâmicos
            $cadastraresposta=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO form_respostas(perguntaid,username,reposta)VALUES(:perguntaid,$name,:resposta)");
            foreach ($listarpergunta as $pergunta) {
                if ($_POST["pergunta$pergunta->id"] != null):
                    $resposta=addslashes($_POST["pergunta$pergunta->id"]);
                    $cadastraresposta->bindParam(":perguntaid",$pergunta->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $cadastraresposta->bindParam(":resposta",$resposta);
                    $cadastraresposta->execute();
                    var_dump($cadastraresposta->execute());
                else:
                    $pdo->rollBack();
                    die("Preencha todos os campos corretamente!<br />");
                endif;
            }
            // Todos os arquivos foram preenchidos corretamente
            //$pdo->commit();
            echo "Obrigado!";
        }
        catch(PDOException $pe){
             //$pdo->rollback();
             die($pe->getMessage());
        }
    else:
?>
```

As querys de INSERT dentro do foreach não fazem nada no banco de dados e esse var_dump me retorna um valor "boolean false". O que devo fazer?

Comment: O PHP está configurado para exibir os erros?

Comment: Prepared Statements: voce está fazendo isso errado

Answer (score 2):

Acho que tem que acionar o bind fora do foreach, tenta assim:

```
$cadastraresposta=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO form_respostas(perguntaid,username,reposta)VALUES(:perguntaid,$name,:resposta)");
$cadastraresposta->bindParam(":perguntaid",$perguntaid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$cadastraresposta->bindParam(":resposta",$resposta);
foreach ($listarpergunta as $pergunta) {
    if ($_POST["pergunta$pergunta->id"] != null):
        $perguntaid=$pergunta->id;
        $resposta=addslashes($_POST["pergunta$pergunta->id"]);
        $cadastraresposta->execute();
    else:
        $pdo->rollBack();
        die("Preencha todos os campos corretamente!<br />");
    endif;
}
```

Manual PHP:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepared-statements.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Obrigado pela dica mas infelizmente não obtive sucesso. Preciso utilizar o foreach por se tratar de um formulário com adição de campos dinamicamente, cadastrados no banco de dados...

Comment: Eu não retirei o foreach, apenas retirei o bindparam de dentro dele, consulte o manual o bind não precisa repetir...

Comment: Mas o bind não teria que vir depois da variável? Lembrando que $resposta passa mais de um resultado por causa do post dinâmico...

Comment: Não, você especifica que quer escutar aquela variável para aquele parâmetro, então se ela mudar de valor, o comando `$cadastraresposta->execute();` vai pegar o valor atual da variável,

Answer (score 1):

Vejo alguns problemas no código.

1. O Jader está correto, o `bindParam` deveria ser necessário somente uma vez, fora do `foreach`, do contrário, nem faria sentido ter uma variável extra e esta função não seria desta forma;
2. Não acho muito seguro escrever `"pergunta$pergunta->id"`, pode ser que o PHP use o `$pergunta` como variável e continue com o texto "->id".
3. Se o índice de array não existe no array `$_POST` uma chamada retorna `null`?

Sugestões:

1. Aceitar a sugestão do Jader;
2. Use uma outra variável para o bind do id da pergunta. Pode não ser necessário, mas me parece mais simples;
3. Reescreva os índices de `$_POST` como `"pergunta${perguntaId}"` ou algo parecido, que pode ser mais confiável;
4. Nossa, nem sabia que o `if` podia ser escrito assim. O tradicional não é mais legível e com maior suporte dos editores de código?
5. Eu acho que ao utilizar bind, as strings não precisam ser tratadas com addslashes, porém você deve testar esta parte pois não tenho certeza;
6. Vou deixar o teste por `null`, mas pode ser necessário mudar, não lembro de como é de fato.
7. Verifique a variável `$name`;
8. Eu, particularmente, gosto de inicializar as variáveis antes do uso;
9. Jader observou a falta de delimitadores de string na query, substituindo para `'name'`.

A parte em questão do código ficaria assim:

```
// Validação dos campos dinâmicos
$cadastraresposta=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO form_respostas (perguntaid, username, reposta) VALUES (:perguntaid, '$name', :resposta)");
$perguntaId = 0;
$resposta = 0;
$cadastraresposta->bindParam(":perguntaid", $perguntaId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$cadastraresposta->bindParam(":resposta", $resposta);
foreach ($listarpergunta as $pergunta) {
  $perguntaId = $pergunta->id;
  $resposta = $_POST["pergunta${perguntaId}"];
  if ($resposta != null) {
    $cadastraresposta->execute();
    if ($cadastraresposta->errorCode() != 0) {
      print_r($cadastraresposta->errorInfo());
      die("Erro ao executar Query!");
    }
  } else {
    $pdo->rollBack();
    die("Preencha todos os campos corretamente!<br />");
  }
}
// Todos os arquivos foram preenchidos corretamente
//$pdo->commit();
echo "Obrigado!";
```

Se não funcionar, tente ver o que tem de errado com o `PDO::errorCode` ou `PDO::errorInfo`.

Comment: sobre o #4, é uma forma muito usada em views, por ser mais fácil encontrar o inicio e fim do que `{...}`... #8, `$perguntaId = 0` definir como zero não faz sentido algum

Comment: Como o Papa Charlie disse, também não entendi a definição da variável como 0, mesmo assim não funcionou. Dei um echo nas variáveis do post e elas retornam o valor corretamente, não sei porque não está inserindo... Quem sabe alguma forma melhor que o foreach para fazer isso?

Comment: Verifique na query onde você tem `,$name,` acho que deve ser `,'$name',`

Comment: @Jader Bem observado, vou editar a resposta. @PapaCharlie Prefiro o tradicional mas é bom saber da outra forma, quanto a atribuir zero, podia ser qualquer número ou string, só gosto de inicializar. Além disso, `bindParam` precisa de uma referência e não gosto de confiar em coisas muito automáticas. @MatheusMelo Verifique a observação do Jader.

Comment: Sua frase "gosto de inicializar" me lembrou quando programava em ASP. Não me referi exclusivamente ao `bindParam`, mas sim à declaração de quaisquer variaveis com atributo 0 ou null antes de se inserir um valor real.

Comment: @MateusMelo Verifique a observação do Jader sobre limitar a string `$name` no SQL, verifique também se ocorre erro na query, adicionei o código para verificar na resposta. Há alguma saída (qualquer) no html?

Answer (score -2):

O post é antigo mas deve ajudar no futuro; A solução é utilizar o bindValue ao invés do bindParam.

Comment: Olá user3474474, você poderia dar um exemplo concreto de código?